# Spark-Scala read multiple files and move to other directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have multiple Csv files in hdfs and some of them not in good format, I would like to read the directory of csv files and then if successfully move the files to other directory. How can I achieve this using spark-scala

Comment: Could you post what have you tried until now.

Comment: read and move? why then spark is needed?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)

val srcPath = "dbfs:/src/"
val dest = "dbfs:/dest/"
val ls      = fs.listStatus(new Path(srcPath))

ls.foreach{ p => {
  if(true) spark.read.csv(p.getPath.toString).write.csv(dest + p.getName)
  else println("File ${p.getName} got wrong format")
}}
```